# Proportional Editing Heat Map viewport

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

Does anyone know of an add-on that would allow you to toggle the viewport of proportional editing? I have an image showing what I mean. But in 3DS Max when in proportional editing they show a heat map fall off of vertices that are affected. I think this is a better way to view proportional editing than just a large circle showing roughly the scale of what is affected.

[image]

Also if anyone knows where I could submit this for a feature request that would be helpful (being optimistic and wishful)

thanks in advance!

Comment: I like it! I don't know any addon that do that already. Feature requests can be submitted and discussed on https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/